# Pre fetching images before adapter is set to recyclerview

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am fetching all the images from array before the array is set to `recyclerview`. I have used Universal image loader for the same. But i have noticed that images are fetched in reverse order.

> ImageLoaderConfiguration is as follows.

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context);
        config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
        config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
        config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator());
        config.diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024); // 50 MiB
        config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
```

and DisplayOption is as given below :

```
DisplayImageOptions.Builder() options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                //.displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(1000))
                //.showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.black)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
//                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

And multiple images are also displayed at once. It should be sequential .